# Vanishing of second cohomology of certain rank $2$ bundles on surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathcal F$ be a locally free sheaf of rank $2$ over a surface $X$ in $\mathbb P^3$. If we have $det(\mathcal F)\cong \mathcal O_X(3)$ and $K_X \cong \mathcal O_X(1)$,then does it necessarily follow that $H^2(\mathcal F) =0$ ? [$K_X :=$ canonical bundle on $X$]

By Serre duality we have, $H^2(\mathcal F) \cong (H^0( \mathcal F^* \otimes \mathcal O_X(1)))^*= (H^0( \mathcal F \otimes \mathcal O_X(-2)))^*$.

I don't see why the last part should vanish.

Any help from anyone is welcome

Comment: Of course not; take, e.g., $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{O}_X(1) \oplus \mathcal{O}_X(2)$.

Comment: @Sasha, Is it because in this case we have an injective map $H^0(\mathcal O_X) \to H^0(\mathcal F \otimes \mathcal O_X(-2))$ ?.What if we assume $\mathcal F$ is stable with respect to $\mathcal O_X(1)$ ?